# How TThreadedSelectorServer support saml ？

Tags: python, java, thrift, thrift-protocol

How to using SAML with TThreadedSelectorServer ? i really can not find any articals  for it.
In my understanding, TThreadedSelectorServer is an advanced server based on NIO, so I want to use SAML together

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what Thrift does.. it's a way to create server side stubs.. but you still must write logic yourself.. including handling SAML

if you have a more specific question I think it'd be easier to offer advice how to get started

Comment: I am referring to spark thrift server to implement a thrift server that supports hive clients, but in spark source code, ThriftBinaryCLIService is a server based on TThreadPoolServer.

 

I don't understand why you don't use TThreadedSelectorServer ? Also, I want to learn whether TThreadedSelectorServer can be used to implement hive thrift server.

However, when I see that TSaslServerTransport is used to create TTransportFactory in spark, I am unfamiliar with SASL, and many articles explain that TSaslServerTransport does not support TThreadedSelectorServer . Is this correct?

Comment: you'd likely only get a clearer response from contributors to the thrift project.. these details I cannot really comment on as a novice myself, unfortunately 

https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/THRIFT/issues/